# Robocopy has erroneously moved important files; but why?

Tags: windows, robocopy

A few days ago I've used robocopy to copy all contents of an old hard-disk to a network volume, but today discovered robocopy had decided to *also* move all of my files in `C:\Users`, while my listed source was `G:/`. Hoping to prevent an annoying and confusing issue to crop up again (couldn't sign in to any local account) I'm turning to you in hopes it could've been something stupid from my end rather then a bug/flaw.

I'd used the following exact syntax:

```
robocopy G:/ "\\annihlogy\annihlation\backups\2012 era 2TB"  *.* /TBD /TEE /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /MOVE /ZB /XX /MT:8 /R:10 /W:30
```

Answer (score 0):

**Robocopy** 
has 3 parameters `Robocopy source destination file`
You are using `COPY` optional parameter which is in
this case pointless. `COPY` specifies if you want copy
`DAT, ATTRIB or TIMESTAMPS` which you are configuring with `/DCOPY`
Everything seems fine, check if you don't have some simlinks on G:\
path which can include C:\Users data.

Comment: COPY is used for defining what to copy on file-level and DCOPY on directory level. /COPY:DAT is the default setting and got included thanks to the logfile including defaults but is not the cause of the error.    Ill take a look if theres any such symlinks tho thanks for the tip!

Comment: checking how the recursion now exists in some folders and using an undamaged system for reference points out robocopy managed to find a synlink for whichever reason pointing to just C:/Users and from there went on and dtarted moving files off the C-drive. Im now busy trying to manually restore the missing files and symlinks but thus far that seems to break even more stuff. Most annoying is that I apparently cant create another user to have a clean profile to start with... all dialogs just do nothing when clicking on the final "next"... i honestly dont get why robocopy doesnt "get" junctions...